# Nth Day of Christmas with recursion in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to solve this with recursion, but I am having trouble figuring out whats wrong. Create a function where given n days as an argument, return the total amount of items received throughout Christmas days as an integer.

xmasItems(1) = 1

xmasItems(3) = 10 : Day1 = (1), Day2 = (1+2), Day3 = (1+2+3) | Day 3 total = (1)+ (1+2) + (1+2+3) = 10

```
int xmasItems(int n) {
    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    else {
        int forThatDay = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            forThatDay += n;
            n--;
        }
        return forThatDay + xmasItems(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `while` loop of your `else` branch, you are decrementing `n` all the way to `0`. So you are computing *only* the first day's value.

Instead, you could use a copy of `n` for the `forThatDay` calculation, so you can make the recursive call correctly:

```
int xmasItems(int n) {
    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    else {
        int forThatDay = 0;
        int m = n;           // copy n and use it
        while (m != 0) {
            forThatDay += m;
            m--;
        }
        return forThatDay + xmasItems(n - 1);  // now n is correct 
    }
}
```

Aside: there is a closed form solution for the [sum of `n` natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), so you shouldn't need a loop anyway.